# How to find out when an application was installed and when the applications/libraries it depends on are installed?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, upgrade

On Ubuntu 12.04, how can I find out

- when an application was installed and
- when the applications/libraries it depends on are installed/upgraded/updated?

My Okular doesn't work any more. I guess it might be because something it depends on has been upgraded.

Comment: Look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` for history of installations/removals using `apt`.